# Typedef not a member of namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef

So, I'm attempting to fork some open source code and upon compilation I am greeted with these errors:

> C2039 'TransactionId': is not a member of 'CryptoNote'
>
> C2061 syntax error: identifier 'TransactionId'

I'm relatively inexperienced with `C++` usually confining myself to the realms of `C#`, however, I can clearly see that `TransactionId` is a `typedef` declared in a different file like so:

```
namespace CryptoNote {

typedef size_t TransactionId;
typedef size_t TransferId;
//more code
```

And the line throwing the error is:

```
  void sendTransactionCompleted(CryptoNote::TransactionId _id, bool _error, const QString& _error_text);
```

To my inexperienced eyes, that looks as though `TransactionID` is definitly a member of `Cryptonote` is it not?

Any ideas what's going on?

The repo is here: https://github.com/hughesjs/Incendium_GUI

And the necessary submodule is here: https://github.com/hughesjs/Incendium_Crypt

Comment: Is the typedef visible from the location of use?

Comment: It might be a visibility issue, since I can't [reproduce the error](https://repl.it/repls/UsableKnottyTrialsoftware).

Comment: Also, why is this tagged with `cmake` and `msbuild`?

Comment: Is `CryptoNote` nested under yet another namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those typedefs are defined in `Incendium_Crypt/include/IWalletLegacy.h`.

```
void sendTransactionCompleted(CryptoNote::TransactionId _id, bool _error, const QString& _error_text);`
```

is defined in `Incendium_GUI/src/gui/SendFrame.h`, which includes `IWallet.h`. However, `IWallet.h` does **not** in turn include `IWalletLegacy.h`. Hence, those typedefs are unknown to `SendFrame.h`.

Comment: Ahh right, adding the typedef to SendFrame.h let it compile, there're some issues with the linker now but that's for a different question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing all the code but a few things come to mind:

- Firstly is this the first error you get.  Compilation errors with C++ tend to result in a bunch of secondary errors.  For example the following results in a similar error to what you see but fails to compile because `size_t` has not been defined:

  namespace CryptoNote {

  typedef size_t TransactionId;
  typedef size_t TransferId;

  }

  int main(void)
  {
      CryptoNote::TransactionId id;
      return 0;
  }

  $ g++ -std=c++11 namespace.cxx -o namespace
  namespace.cxx:4:9: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
   typedef size_t TransactionId;
           ^~~~~~
  namespace.cxx:5:9: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
   typedef size_t TransferId;
           ^~~~~~
  namespace.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
  namespace.cxx:11:17: error: ‘TransactionId’ is not a member of ‘CryptoNote’
       CryptoNote::TransactionId id;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/ for a list of headers that define `size_t`.

- Is `CryptoNote` nested inside another namespace?
- Is there another `CryptoNote` defined in the namespace your function is declared in?
- Are these in the same header file?  If not, is the header file where the namespace is defined included in the header file containing the function declaration?